# Ionic 4 Random page loading

Tags: ionic-framework, root, ionic4

So i have an ionic 4 app. And what've noticed is that it first opens My SettingsPage. Before it just opened the /tabs/tab1 page so i tried doing: `this.router.navigateByUrl('/tabs/tab1');` in the app.component.ts but than it will load SettingsPage first and than the tabs/tab1 page.

For the appfolder go to this [link](https://mega.nz/#!5xdwCaKA!0gbTQ5a0JyhUeuTzBmbeItMw_klRzbHD-BfX3O0aE7g)

Comment: The link provided asks for the decryption key, I can't see app folder without decryption key

Comment: @VarunSukheja can you try again. I'm sorry

Comment: @VarunSukheja Can you maybe look at this still haven't found how and why

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I was unable to run your project, as the link contains just the app folder and not the complete project.

I tried to check your routes and here are some mistakes I found:

This is you app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: './tabs/tabs.module#TabsPageModule'
    }
];
```

In above code snippet I removed the extra routes which might be added when you tried to generate your module/pages by CLI. Since we are using tabs design so all the primary routes will be controlled by the routing module of tabs module.

This is tabs.router.module.ts file

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'tabs',
        component: TabsPage,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'tab1',
                children: [
                    {
                        path: '',
                        loadChildren: '../tab1/tab1.module#Tab1PageModule'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                path: 'tab2',
                children: [
                    {
                        path: '',
                        loadChildren: '../tab2/tab2.module#Tab2PageModule'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                path: 'tab3',
                children: [
                    {
                        path: '',
                        loadChildren: '../tab3/tab3.module#Tab3PageModule'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                path: 'settings',
                children: [
                    {
                        path: '',
                        loadChildren: '../settings/settings.module#SettingsPageModule'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                path: '',
                redirectTo: '/tabs/tab1',
                pathMatch: 'full'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/tabs/tab1',
        pathMatch: 'full'
    }
];
```

If you notice in above code, inside the routes array just after the settings route I added default route which means if only /tabs is entered in the browser, it will take you to /tabs/tab1 route.

Comment: Yes i see now, thank you. I am very new at angular i only knew the ionic 3 stuff they had. But how do i set a RootPage so i don;t want the tabs/tab1 to be the root but i want to getting-started page to be the root and how do i set a the root whenever you login as example or if is there a documentation somewhere that i can read because i couldn't find anything